# same as what she said vs same as she said

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, meaning-in-context, linguistics, sentence-meaning

I have some questions confusing me.

(I work in a cafe.)

1. Is this the same order as she said.
2. Is this the same order as what she said.

What is the difference between 1 and 2 and which one is correct?

3. Is this the same as she said
4. Is this the same as what she said.

Do 3, 4 have the same meaning as 1, 2?

Comment: While some of these are preferable to others, I would avoid all four.

Comment: The examples are unnatural; people don't *say* orders, they *make* or *give* them them, depending on the context. (*Made* is for ordering food, and *gave* is for issuing a command.)  It would be better (although still not completely natural) to compare (1) *Is this the same order as she (made / gave)?* with (2) Is this the same order as **what** she she (made / gave)?*

Comment: Note that sentence 3 and 4 sound a lot more natural than 1 and 2, and are actually what I might expect to be said. (I would never expect to hear 1 or 2.)

Comment: "Is this the same as her order" or "is this the same order as hers" would be more natural. "Is this her order" would mean that you were asking if this was her actual order rather than one just like it.

Comment: Thx for replies but my questions are not answered yet. I think I should've said the situation. She is not the one who made the order and it doesn't matter which one is more natural. I just want to know grammatically what is the difference between with what and without what. Reading these comments, I guess 1,2,3,4 are grammatically correct. Right?

Comment: (There were 4 people in this conversation, a customer, employee 1, employee 2, and me. A customer ordered a coffee to employee 1. Employee 2 overheard it. Employee 1 had told me this order. Later employee 2 told me again without knowing employee 1 already told me. So I asked employee 2, is this the same order as the employee 1 said. This is the whole situation.)